# Optional Time parameter

Tags: sql, oracle, date

Table 1 :

```
Name Date
A    01-JAN-2015
B    03-DEC-2016
```

I want to write a SQL , that makes Date parameter as option

```
select * from Table 1 where :Date = Date or :Date is null;
```

i.e. when null value is passed it should display

```
Name Date
A    01-JAN-2015
B    03-DEC-2016
```

when i select 01-JAN-2015 as :Date

it should display

```
name Date
A    01-JAN-2015
```

i tried many option but am not able to achieve it .please help me .gratitude.

Comment: Is your table name really called table 1?? Then you need to call it "table 1". You need that if you have a space. Can you show us what "am not able to achieve it" means? You have an error? What error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. "Table" and "Date" are Oracle's reserved words. Don't use them as identifiers (column name, variable name, column alias etc.)
2. Use "to_date" function with format_mask 'DD-MON-RRRR' to explicit conversion "string" to "date" datatypes.

Your statement could be like this:

```
select * 
from table_a 
where to_date(:Date_a, 'DD-MON-YYYY')=date_a or :Date_a is null;
```